# Prove that a surreal number is born in a finite stage if and only if it is of the form $\frac m{2^n}$.

Tags: induction, surreal-numbers

We define surreal numbers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number). My attempt is to first prove this lemma:

> **Lemma 1.** Suppose in the $n$th stage, we have already constructed 2 surreals $a<b$, with no other surreals constructed between them. Then $$2\cdot\{a|b\}=a+b.$$

From this I can quite easily deduce the desired result. So now the difficulty lies in proving the lemma.

I have tried to expand the multiplication, and using the definition that $x=y\Leftrightarrow x\le y$ and $x\ge y$. Doing this I get something that, apparently, needs to be further simplified. However, using the definitions of inequalities breaks it up into more and more pieces, and I don't see anywhere that I can use induction. Also, I can't utilize the condition that $a$ and $b$ are 'adjacent'.

Is there a way to prove this lemma? Or am I going in the wrong direction? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{surr}[2]{\left\{ #1 \mathbin{\big\vert} #2 \right\}}$
Conway's proof of the question in your title in *On Numbers and Games* is by a different and rather cleverly indirect argument.  First, he proves that the surreal numbers form an ordered field.  He also proves that any number $\surr{a}{b}$ is equal to the simplest number which is greater than $a$ and less than $b$. (where "simplest" means "constructed in the earliest stage").  Then, he proves the following lemma.

> **Lemma** (Theorem 12 of ONAG): Suppose $x=\frac{\ell}{2^m}$ for some integer $\ell$.  Then $x=\surr{x-\frac{1}{2^m}}{x+\frac{1}{2^m}}$.
>
> *Proof*: We use induction on $m$.  For $m=0$ this is easy, since $x$ is an integer and so if $x\geq 0$ then $x$ is the simplest number greater than $x-1$ and if $x<0$ then $x$ is the simplest number less than $x+1$.
>
> Now suppose $m>0$ and we already know the result for $m-1$.  Let $z=\surr{x-\frac{1}{2^m}}{x+\frac{1}{2^m}}$.  Using the definition of addition, we find $$2z=z+z=\surr{z+x-\frac{1}{2^m}}{z+x+\frac{1}{2^m}}.$$  By the induction hypothesis, we know that $2x=\surr{2x-\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}}{2x+\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}}$, since $2x=\frac{2\ell}{2^{m-1}}$.  Thus $2x$ is the simplest number between $2x-\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}$ and $2x+\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}$, and so it is also the simplest number between $z+x-\frac{1}{2^m}$ and $z+x+\frac{1}{2^m}$ since $$2x-\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}< z+x-\frac{1}{2^m} < 2x < z+x+\frac{1}{2^m}<2x+\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}$$ (these inequalities follow from $x-\frac{1}{2^m}<z<x+\frac{1}{2^m}$).  Looking back at our expression for $2z$ above, this shows that $2x=2z$, and hence $x=z$ as desired.

Given this lemma, it is then straightforward to completely describe what the $n$th stage of the surreal numbers looks like by induction on $n$.  Specifically, if $n>0$ then after the $n$th stage the surreal numbers constructed so far are exactly those of the form $\pm\left(i+\frac{j}{2^k}\right)$ for $i,j,k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $j\leq 2^k$ and $i+k<n$.  For the induction step, then, the $(n+1)$st stage will have the same form because every pair of consecutive numbers $a<b$ constructed after the $n$th stage can be written in the form $a=x-\frac{1}{2^m}$ and $b=x+\frac{1}{2^m}$ for some dyadic rational $x$ with denominator $2^m$, and so the new number $\surr{a}{b}$ will be $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ by the lemma.

---

Let me finish with some observations on your proposed proof strategy in comparison with Conway's.  As far as I know, there isn't any nice way to prove your lemma in isolation.  The problem is that the assumption that there are no numbers between $a$ and $b$ constructed so far is not easy to use.  You can only really make good use of it if you *already* know exactly what all the surreal numbers constructed up to the $n$th stage look like.  So, your lemma needs to not be a separate lemma proved first, but instead embedded in an inductive proof of a description of the $n$th stage so that you can use the induction hypothesis to get a handle on what $a$ and $b$ can be.  That's exactly what the argument above does, to reduce your lemma to Conway's lemma.

Comment: This is precisely what I wanted. Could you please tell me the complete book name? Thank you so much :)

Comment: ONAG is _On Numbers and Games_ by John Conway.  It's the original monograph by Conway that introduced surreal numbers and combinatorial game theory in its modern formulation.